# Open Graph head meta tags not accessible to Facebook Crawler

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-4, facebook-graph-api, web-crawler, meta-tags

I am trying to allow the Facebook Crawler to access the meta information with Open Graph tags on a site, but it is not reading the inner content of the head tag.

If I echo the scrape information, it shows the head tag as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></head>
<body>

 ...
```

At the source of the page, however, the head information contains the meta tags:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# article: http://ogp.me/ns/article#">
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <meta name="referrer" content="always" />
  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="375576830972731" />
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="Site Name" />
  <meta property="og:title" content="Title of content" />
  <meta property="og:url" content="https://website.domain.com/123456" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/domain/media/images/001/original/001" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="Description of content" />
  <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
</head>
```

My controller is set up to allow a `protect_from_forgery" exception, and I made sure to allow for the Facebook crawlers in robots.txt:

```
User-agent: Facebot
Allow: /

User-agent: facebookexternalhit/1.1
Allow: /
```

Why can't Facebook's crawler get to the meta tags in my header?

Comment: Have you [validated](http://validator.w3.org/) your HTML? Example URL, so that we can have a look at the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by changing the `respond_to` block in the controller for the articles I was trying to display.

I had something like this:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  def show
  ...

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html
    end
  end

end
```

However, I noticed that when I executed `curl https://website.domain.com/123456`, the first thing returned was a javascript function associated with the view, instead of the proper html tags.

Placing `format.html` before `format.js` solved this issue.

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  def show
  ...

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: dear , please have a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36232662/small-preview-when-sharing-link-on-social-media-ruby-on-rails

Comment: i want to do the same thing but i'm alot confuse